# Priority Queue returns wrong order

Tags: go

I edited a bit the official [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/#example__priorityQueue) on Priority Queue and I found an interesting behavior: the order gets messed up.

Specifically, I updated this line:

```
item := heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item)
```

with this line (now pointing to the implemented method itself)

```
item := pq.Pop().(*Item)
```

> Results are now: `03:banana 02:apple 04:pear`

Why are the results different? Why are the 2 methods (heap.Pop and *pq.Pop) named the same if they perform different function. It leads to confusion.

```
package main

import (
    "container/heap"
    "fmt"
)

// An Item is something we manage in a priority queue.
type Item struct {
    value    string // The value of the item; arbitrary.
    priority int    // The priority of the item in the queue.
    // The index is needed by update and is maintained by the heap.Interface methods.
    index int // The index of the item in the heap.
}

// A PriorityQueue implements heap.Interface and holds Items.
type PriorityQueue []*Item

func (pq PriorityQueue) Len() int { return len(pq) }

func (pq PriorityQueue) Less(i, j int) bool {
    // We want Pop to give us the highest, not lowest, priority so we use greater than here.
    return pq[i].priority > pq[j].priority
}

func (pq PriorityQueue) Swap(i, j int) {
    pq[i], pq[j] = pq[j], pq[i]
    pq[i].index = i
    pq[j].index = j
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Push(x interface{}) {
    n := len(*pq)
    item := x.(*Item)
    item.index = n
    *pq = append(*pq, item)
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Pop() interface{} {
    old := *pq
    n := len(old)
    item := old[n-1]
    old[n-1] = nil  // avoid memory leak
    item.index = -1 // for safety
    *pq = old[0 : n-1]
    return item
}

// update modifies the priority and value of an Item in the queue.
func (pq *PriorityQueue) update(item *Item, value string, priority int) {
    item.value = value
    item.priority = priority
    heap.Fix(pq, item.index)
}

// This example creates a PriorityQueue with some items, adds and manipulates an item,
// and then removes the items in priority order.
func main() {
    // Some items and their priorities.
    items := map[string]int{
        "banana": 3, "apple": 2, "pear": 4,
    }

    // Create a priority queue, put the items in it, and
    // establish the priority queue (heap) invariants.
    pq := make(PriorityQueue, len(items))
    i := 0
    for value, priority := range items {
        pq[i] = &Item{
            value:    value,
            priority: priority,
            index:    i,
        }
        i++
    }
    heap.Init(&pq)

    // Take the items out; they arrive in decreasing priority order.
    for pq.Len() > 0 {
        //item := heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item)
        item := pq.Pop().(*Item)
        fmt.Printf("%.2d:%s ", item.priority, item.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can look at the source of [`heap.Pop`](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/go1.16.3/src/container/heap/heap.go#60) to see what you are doing differently. You are not setting up the heap to pop the correct item, so I'm not sure how you expect the heap to work when you purposely don't call the correct function.

Comment: They have different behavior because they're different functions with different implementations. Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you observe closly, the `PriorityQueue` actually is just a `[]*Item`. It is defined in documentation that `// A PriorityQueue implements heap.Interface and holds Items`. This heap interface as defined in [documentation](https://golang.org/src/container/heap/heap.go?s=1328:1480#L22):

```
// Note that Push and Pop in this interface are for package heap's
// implementation to call. To add and remove things from the heap,
// use heap.Push and heap.Pop.
type Interface interface {
    sort.Interface
    Push(x interface{}) // add x as element Len()
    Pop() interface{}   // remove and return element Len() - 1.
}
```

So clearly, the priority queue uses heap to work properly. Heap has Push and Pop menthod which then use the methods defined by PriorityQueue to sort, store and prioritise the Items in queue.
What you did just displays the list as you stored it. There was no sorting and prioritising happening in the process.